# How can I add an additional variable to the query in Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an AJAX code that sorts the items by DATE, but I want to sort the items by category too.

I want to use a drop down menu for choosing the categories.

I pass the category variable through the URL by calling the page with the AJAX code (which then calls the MySQL query page).

I had this code:

```
var datumfree = 0;

var month = new Array();
month[0] = "Jan";
month[1] = "Feb";
month[2] = "Mar";
month[3] = "Apr";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "Aug";
month[8] = "Sept";
month[9] = "Oct";
month[10] = "Nov";
month[11] = "Dec";

$(document).ready(function() {



    function refresh(free){

        $("#loadingfree").show();

        if (free) datumfree = datumfree + free;
    var url = "listcategory.php?date=" + datumfree;
    $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
```

Now I tried to do something like this:

```
var datumfree = 0;
var category = '$category';

var month = new Array();
month[0] = "Jan";
month[1] = "Feb";
month[2] = "Mar";
month[3] = "Apr";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "Aug";
month[8] = "Sept";
month[9] = "Oct";
month[10] = "Nov";
month[11] = "Dec";

$(document).ready(function() {



    function refresh(free){

        $("#loadingfree").show();

        if (free) datumfree = datumfree + free;
    var url = "listcategory.php?date=" + datumfree + "&category=" + category;
    $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
```

I know that it's probably idiotic, but I am a beginner in PHP and I have absolutely no clue about AJAX, so any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Just a term correction that may help you out: The language you are writing is JavaScript. These calls like `$.getJSON` are AJAX methods which allow you to interact with the server/APIs without having to refresh the page. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Now to answer the question, what is the problem? I see you are not doing anything with data after you make the request so you won't really know if you have it. Are you getting an error in the console or something?

Comment: have you read this : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Why is you `refresh` function inside your $(document).ready(). You should place it outside that scope.

Comment: @Chax, because reasons :-) The page has to refresh on first load so it can be populated, otherwise I have an empty page until somebody clicks something.

Comment: @Jordan: The code goes of course further. It also works for getting data for the actual day (or the day I choose). All I want to do is being able to make a query by category too. In addition to the day, so I can display only categoryX for the dayY.

Comment: sounds good enough. Good thing you found out. Happy coding mate

Answer (score 1):

To get the category value from the category dropdownlist, if id is there for the dropdown use `$("#id_you_gave").val()` and then in your listcategory.php page you have `$_GET['date']` for getting the date value passed from the ajax. In similar way you need to add `$_GET['category']` to get category and add this to the sql query of mysql.(The way we will send the parameters in ajax is key and value like date="datevalue"&category="categoryValue". So we need use key in the $_GET[''] if get request or $_POST[''] if post request in php to get the values what we passed in ajax)

Comment: You mean so? `var category = $("#category").val()`

Comment: yes, if category drop down has id attribute as "category"

Comment: Ok, thanks! It doesn't work yet, but hopefully I can fix it. What I do is having a header on my main page. In that header is the dropdown. Now if I choose an item (category) from the dropdown, the page with this code loads, which then loads the page of the MySQL code. I am not sure if it's not a problem that it goes through 3 pages.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

It works now.

This is what I did:

```
var datumfree = 0;
var category = '<?php echo $_POST['category']; ?>';

var month = new Array();
month[0] = "Jan";
month[1] = "Feb";
month[2] = "Mar";
month[3] = "Apr";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "Aug";
month[8] = "Sept";
month[9] = "Oct";
month[10] = "Nov";
month[11] = "Dec";



$(document).ready(function() {



    function refresh(free){

        $("#loadingfree").show();

        if (free) datumfree = datumfree + free;
    var url = "listcategory.php?date=" +datumfree+ "&category=" + category;
    $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
```